# How is the Fractal Dimension of a Parametric Curve Related to the Fractal Dimensions of its Coordinate Functions?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

**Question:**
Suppose the fractal dimension $1\le d_c\le2$ of a planar parametric curve $c(t) := (x(t),y(t))$ is given;
can any nontrivial estimates for the fractal dimensions $d_x$ of $x(t)$ and $d_y$ of $y(t)$ be given?

Comment: There is some interesting work computing the coordinate functionals for the standard space-filling curves $d_c=2$.  One example: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1285689164

Answer (score 4):

No nontrivial estimates, at least if the definitions are right.

Say let's define
$$\ell_\alpha c=\sup\,\left\{\,\sum_{t_0<\dots<t_n}|c(t_i)-c(t_{i-1})|^\alpha\,\right\}$$
and
$$\dim c=\sup\{\,\alpha\mid \ell_\alpha c<\infty\,\}.$$

Then from Pythagorean theorem we get
$$\dim c=\max\{\dim x, \dim y\}.$$